# Changing the titles form with the documentclass amsart?

Tags: titles, amsart

I have written an article using the document class `amsart`, but I found that the titles are written in all-MAJUSCULES (aka uppercase letters). Do you know how I can control the style of the titles. I want them to be in bold and minuscules.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: When you write "minuscules", you you mean small-caps?

Comment: I mean by minscules lower case lettres and majescules Upper case.

Comment: Please provide an [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we know exactly what is going on. Otherwise, all we can do is guess ...

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703479/579  Where it has `\boldmath`, substitute `\bfseries`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that you don't really want minuscules (= all in lower case letters) but mixed case (upper case, when you type upper case, lower case, when you type lower case).

You can patch `\@settitle` adding following to your document preamble:

```latex
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@settitle}{\uppercasenonmath\@title}{\boldmath}{}{\PatchFailure}
\makeatother
```

It removes the change of `\@title` to upper case and adds selection of bold math font (bold text is already part of the default).

As you've told in a comment, despite you've used tag [titles](/questions/tagged/titles) not the document titles are the problem, but the section headings. Note, `amsart` does not use majuscules (all upper case) for the section headings, but small caps. You also can patch `\section` to remove them and use, e.g., bold series instead:

```latex
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\section}{\scshape}{\bfseries}{}{\PatchFailure}
```

Note: The shown code is not tested, because you've not shown a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) that could be used to reproduce the problem and to test my idea.

Comment: I use the classdocument{amsart}, but with this class the titles of sections are written in Upper case letters for example Section 1 title is "COMMUTATIVES RINGS", but I want the titles to be written like "Commutative rings"

Comment: @LatifaMalki So the question is not about [`titles`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titles) as you have told us using this tag for your question, but about [`sectioning`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sectioning). Once again proof that I should not try to answer questions without [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964). BTW: AFAIK `amsart` does not use majuscules but small caps.